# Is there a way to make QToolButton's arrow bigger

Tags: qt, qt5

On a small screen, it's really hard to hit the small arrow to show the menu of a QToolButton. Is there a way to make the clickable area larger. Unfortunately QToolButton::InstantPopup doesn't trigger the button's own action, it would have been perfect otherwise.

Comment: I see that with InstantPopup you can open the menu by pressing anywhere on the button, what is your problem? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What about `QToolButton::DelayedPopup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet of the qtoolbutton can be modifed as followed:

```
QToolButton[popupMode="1"] { /* only for MenuButtonPopup */
padding-right: 20px; /* make way for the popup button */
}
/* the subcontrols below are used only in the MenuButtonPopup mode */
QToolButton::menu-button {
border: 2px solid gray;
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
/* 16px width + 4px for border = 20px allocated above */
width: 16px;
```

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html